# Specializing template member function

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I'm trying to specify a function of a template class, that should only work when an object of the class is created using specific types (KEY as `std::string` and VALUE as `std::string`).

My template (`Dictionary.h`), simplified:

```
#ifndef QB_DICTIONARY_H
#define QB_DICTIONARY_H

#include <map>
#include <string>

namespace QB {
    template<typename KEY, typename VALUE, typename COMPARE = std::less<KEY>>
    class Dictionary {
    public:
        typedef typename std::map<KEY, VALUE, COMPARE>::iterator iterator;
        typedef typename std::map<KEY, VALUE, COMPARE>::const_iterator const_iterator;

        Dictionary() {
        }

        Dictionary(const std::map<KEY, VALUE, COMPARE> & value) {
            this->value = value;
        }

        typename iterator begin() {
            return value.begin();
        }

        typename const_iterator begin() const {
            return value.cbegin();
        }

        typename iterator end() {
            return value.end();
        }

        typename const_iterator end() const {
            return value.cend();
        }

        // Trying to have the function work only when the template KEY and VALUE are of type std::string
        const std::string implode<std::string, std::string>(const std::string & valueSeparator, const std::string & pairSeparator) const {
            std::string result;

            for (iterator i = begin(); i != end(); i++) {
                if (i != begin()) {
                    result += pairSeparator;
                }

                result += iterator->first;
                result += valueSeparator;
                result += iterator->second;
            }

            return result;
        }

    private:
        std::map<KEY, VALUE, COMPARE> value;
    };
}

#endif
```

The implode function is the one I'm trying to implement. Trying to compile the above results in this:

```
1>d:\cloud storage\onedrive\projects\qb\qb\dictionary.h(115): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '<'
1>  d:\cloud storage\onedrive\projects\qb\qb\dictionary.h(133): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'QB::Dictionary<KEY,VALUE,COMPARE>' being compiled
1>d:\cloud storage\onedrive\projects\qb\qb\dictionary.h(115): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
```

I'm not sure how I should implement this. Any hints?

---

**EDIT:**

I've encountered some new problems while trying out @TartanLlama's answer.

My current code is as follows (irrelevant parts left out):
`Dictionary.h`:

```
#ifndef QB_DICTIONARY_H
#define QB_DICTIONARY_H

#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

namespace QB {
    template<typename KEY, typename VALUE, typename COMPARE = std::less<KEY>>
    class Dictionary {
    public:
        // ...

        const std::string implode(const std::string &, const std::string &) const;

        // ...
    };

    template<typename K=KEY, typename V=VALUE, typename COMPARE = std::less<KEY>>
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<std::string, K>{} && std::is_same<std::string, V>{}, const std::string> Dictionary<K, V, COMPARE>::implode(const std::string & valueSeparator, const std::string & pairSeparator) const {
        // ...
    }
}

#endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to explicitly-specialize `implode`, but it's not a template.

You could use SFINAE to only enable the function if `KEY` and `VALUE` are `std::string`:

```
template <typename K=KEY, typename V=VALUE>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<std::string, K>{} &&
                 std::is_same<std::string, V>{}, 
                 const std::string>
implode(const std::string & valueSeparator, 
        const std::string & pairSeparator) const {
    //...
}
```

---

You could use `static_assert` to issue an error if the function is instantiated for the wrong `Dictionary` specialization:

```
implode(const std::string & valueSeparator, 
        const std::string & pairSeparator) const { 
    static_assert(std::is_same<std::string, K>{} &&
                  std::is_same<std::string, V>{},
                  "KEY and VALUE must be std::string");
    //...
}
```

Comment: This could come in handy. It works, so I upvoted it, but coincoin's answer was a bit more elegant. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: @Qub1 one thing to note is that these solutions will give you a compile-time error if you do something wrong, whereas coincoin's solution will give you a link-time error.

Comment: I've noticed that. That could make debugging difficult. Would it be possible to maybe combine both solutions?

Comment: You could provide a definition for the primary template which has a `static_assert` in it.

Comment: I was playing around with SFINAE for a bit and I run into some trouble, when I used your example I got a lot of errors. I also can't find code similar to yours, most use `std::enable_if_t` inside of the `template<>` code. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @Qub1 Using `std::enable_if_t` in the return type should be fine. What kind of errors did you get?

Comment: Well there are about 150 errors, but the one causing it all is `error C2059: syntax error: '<end Parse>'` which occurs on the same line as `std::enable_if_t`.
The function header looks like this: `template<typename KEY, typename VALUE, typename COMPARE = std::less<KEY>>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<KEY, std::string>{} && std::is_same<VALUE, std::string>{}, const std::string> Dictionary<KEY, VALUE, COMPARE>::implode(const std::string & valueSeparator, const std::string & pairSeparator) const {`

Comment: @Qub1 maybe you're using a version of MSVC which doesn't support some of this stuff.

Comment: Is there anywhere I can check the current version I have? AFAIK I have all updates installed, and Visual Studio reports the following Platform Toolset being used: `Visual Studio 2015 (v140)`

Comment: Hm, VS2015 should be fine. Not sure what syntax error it'd be complaining about.

Comment: I've edited my original question and included what my code looks like now. Would you take another look, maybe you can spot the problem?

Comment: @Qub1 Oh, you should just declare and define the template in the class definition. Like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/637d4589c7067503).

Comment: Ah thank you, that made the compiler happy. It's working now. I actually prefer this solution now, as it's proven to be more flexible. I've changed my accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can specialize by explicitly instantiate your method member like this outside your class definition :

```
template<> std::string QB::Dictionary<std::string, std::string>::implode(const std::string & valueSeparator, const std::string & pairSeparator) const {
    std::string result;

    for (const_iterator i = begin(); i != end(); i++) {
        if (i != begin()) {
            result += pairSeparator;
        }

        result += i->first;
        result += valueSeparator;
        result += i->second;
    }

    return result;
}
```

**[Live Code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e37b479a44b8c63e)**

Note that I have fixed other errors (no need to add typename in return method type, use const_iterator...)